# .parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('myClassname') not works, Why?

Tags: jquery

Please see below fiddle link, while applying,

```
.parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('myClassname')
```

code, then jquery dialog not works, need to know the reason.

here is fiddle link,

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/3d7QC/916/)

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a syntax error in the quote!!!

```
.parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar').addClass('myClassname')
// --------------------------------^ Quote error
```

**This works:**

```
.parent().find(".ui-dialog-titlebar").addClass('myClassname')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing quotes and double quotes.